# Jquerytools Tabs taking a second or so to organise themselves on pageload

Tags: tabs, jquery-tools

I am using jquery tools tabs on a corporate site, to show the 5 company directors.

each director has a slide to themselves containing there photo, title, details etc.

however on teh page load... for about half a second, all of the tabs appear before organising themselves and the first slide is present.

is there anyway to make the tabs organise themselves instantly, or at least not appear until all the organising has gone on. I feel it may be a problem with how and where I am placing the scripts.

I am using html5 boilerplate and my scripts are near the bottom of the page.

here is my code (modernizr.js is being called in the header):

```
<!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if offline -->
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div", {
// enable "cross-fading" effect
 effect: 'slide',
// start from the beginning after the last tab
rotate: true
// use the slideshow plugin. It accepts its own configuration
}).slideshow();
});
</script>
<!-- scripts concatenated and minified via build script -->

<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```